# Regular Expression for Validation of files and Special characters

Tags: c#, regex

I have a regex which validates only file to upload `.doc`, `.docx`, `.DOCX`, `.rtf`, and `.pdf`. See below the regex code:

```
"^.+(.doc|.DOC|.docx|.DOCX|.rtf|.RTF|.pdf|.PDF)$"
```

But in this scenario, I also want to validate the file name should not include more than one `.`.

For ex:

A file name should not be like this: `abc.abc.doc` it should be like this: `abc.doc`.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: I am using C#, asp.net

Comment: FYI added a second approach

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two general formulas for what you want to do.

**First approach: say what you want**

```
(?i)^[a-z0-9_-]+\.(?:docx?|rtf|pdf)$
```

The `(?i)` makes it case-insensitive so that you don't have to repeat `doc`, `DOC` etc. For instance, you could have a `doC` or `DoC` extension, but it is not mentioned in the original alternation.

The allowable chars for the prefix are specified in `[a-z0-9_-]`, so if you want more chars you can add them there.

**Second approach: say what you don't want**

Another approach is to allow all characters in the prefix except a dot and perhaps a number of "bad characters":

```
(?i)^[^.<>:"/\\|*?\t\r\n]+\.(?:docx?|rtf|pdf)$
```

Neither will be a perfect fit unless you know exactly what set of characters your file system will allow.

Comment: Hey Thanks zx81, it worked accordingly as required. Hope u might also have gone through this issue.

Comment: Sure zx81, u deserve it..Done as said.
Regards,

Comment: Ya sure, will do..Wish u the same, enjoy, tc...!!
Regards

Comment: +1 for your own built regex, now became know how to use `stack overflow`. This was my first question which I asked

Answer (score 0):

`^[^.]+([.]doc|[.]DOC|[.]docx|[.]DOCX|[.]rtf|[.]RTF|[.]pdf|[.]PDF)$`

`[^.]+` matches one or more characters which are not a period.

EDIT: As Jongware mentioned, the periods inthe "OR" list should match the period literal.

Comment: All the initial periods in the OR list will match *any* character, so this will match `not_a_doc`. (The OP made that same mistake.)